# Replicate variable based off match of two other variables in R

Tags: r, vector, match

I've got a seemingly simple question that I can't answer: I've got three vectors:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
weight <- c(5,6,7,8)
y <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
```

I want to create a new vector that replicates the values of weight for each time an element in x matches y such that it produces the following new weight vector associated with y:

```
y_weight <- c(5,5,5,6,6,6)
```

Any thoughts on how to do this (either loop or vectorized)? Thanks

Comment: `weight[na.omit(match(y,x))]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `match` function.

```
match(y, x)
```

to return the indicies of the matches, the use that to build your new weight vector

```
weight[match(y, x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Using plyr

library(plyr)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,weight)) # converting to dataframe
df<-rename(df,c(x="y")) # rename x as y for joining dataframes
y<-as.data.frame(y) # converting to dataframe
mydata <- join(df, y, by = "y",type="right")
> mydata
  y weight
1 1      5
2 1      5
3 1      5
4 2      6
5 2      6
6 2      6
```